# How to replace text at end of line in text file in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a text file having about 10Mio IDs. Each ID in one line. 
I want to transform this file to a CSV, with a comma as separator. I tried to replace the '\n' in the string with ', \n' but unfortunately, it's doing nothing.

Here is the code I used:

```
s = open("/home/pathHere/filename.txt","r+")
    counter = 0
    for line in s.readlines():
       counter += 1
       line.strip()
       line.replace('\n', ', \n')
       if (counter == 1):
           print(line)
    s.close()
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in python are constants. You need to write

```
line = line.replace('\n', ', \n')
```

Comment: And also line=line.strip()

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But changed it but still not working unfortunately!

Comment: You also need to rewrite the new lines to a new file.